# How to handle failed mongoDB autoreconnect?

Tags: c++, mongodb

Windows 7 SP1
MSVS 2010
MongoDB 2.2.0

Skeletal code:

```
// Successful connection at the start.
mongo::DBClientConnection client_connection(true); // autoreconnect = true

// But (say) by the time we get here mongo has shut down.
try
{
    cursor = client_connection.query(...)
}
catch(const mongo::DBException& ex)
{
    cout << "DBException: " << ex.what() << "//" << ex.toString() << endl;
}
```

The console first prints:

```
Thu Apr 25 14:03:09 Socket say send() errno:10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. 127.0.0.1:27017
```

Then the DBException is caught:

```
DBException: socket exception [SEND_ERROR] for 127.0.0.1:27017 9001 socket exception [2] server [127.0.0.1:27017]
```

Reconnect is attempted:

```
Thu Apr 25 14:03:09 trying reconnect to localhost:27017
Thu Apr 25 14:03:10 reconnect localhost:27017 failed couldn't connect to server localhost:27017
```

And I get:

[image]

**My question:** How would I go about catching this failure to reconnect so I can handle it gracefully?

Comment: most likely your re-connection code does not have similar try/catch code, thus the uncaught exception

Comment: @cha Unfortunately, the re-connection code is somewhere in the underlying mongoDB code. I am hoping that a) There is a catch that I can use or b) there is a different methodology that will handle this for me.

Comment: add catch(...) to your code